# Why are there no concurrency keywords in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, concurrency

Why are there no keywords for synchronization and concurrency?

So far my research gives me one solution, you wrap some high level classes and use them to handle concurrency.

Given a project in pure Kotlin, what should one do if there is a need for a small, highly optimized component that handles concurrency in a thread-safe manner?

My impression is that Kotlin is an assisting language for Java, to write 90% of the code in Kotlin but have some Java code that is not possible to express with Kotlin.

Is this right? Is this how it was intended to be?

Comment: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/concurrency-in-kotlin/858

Comment: Kotlin has synchronized blocks (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/synchronized.html), synchronized methods (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-synchronized/), volatile field (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-volatile/index.html). And it can use java.util.concurrent classes. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: You have more than one question here, you should focus on one topic.  What concurrency things do you think are missing, you specify something that sounds to me like it is NOT missing.  Then the other question isn't really a SO question and is opinion based (and is not a correct assertion).

Comment: see: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines for updates to Kotlin coroutines

Answer (score 187, accepted):

[Kotlin 1.1 with Coroutines was released](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/03/kotlin-1-1/) and it brings with it `async..await`!  Read more about it in [Kotlin reference docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html), [Kotlinx Coroutines library](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines) and this great in depth [Couroutines by Example](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md)

**Outside of the Kotlin Coroutines, you have these options:**

- the [Kovenant library](http://kovenant.komponents.nl/) adds Promises to Kotlin
- the [Quasar library](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/) provides light-weight threads and continuations
- [`@Synchronized`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-synchronized/) and [`@Volatile`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-volatile/index.html) annotations which map directly to the same keywords in Java
- [`synchronized` blocks](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/synchronized.html) which in Kotlin come from an inline function `synchronized()`.
- Kotlin has a [`Kotlin.concurrent` package and extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/index.html) with new functions and also extensions to JDK classes.
- you can access anything in the [`java.util.concurrent` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) such as `ConcurrentHashMap`, `CountdownLatch`, `CyclicBarrier`, `Semaphore`, ...
- you can access anything in the [`java.util.concurrent.locks` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) and Kotlin has [extensions for a few of these](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/index.html) including the cool [`withLock()` extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/java.util.concurrent.locks.-lock/with-lock.html) and similar [`read`/`write` extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/java.util.concurrent.locks.-reentrant-read-write-lock/index.html) for `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.
- you can access anything in the [`java.util.concurrent.atomic` package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) such as `AtomicReference`, `AtomicLong`, ...
- you can use [`wait` and `notify` on objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#waitnotify)

You have everything Java has and more.  Your phrase *"synchronization and locks"* is satisfied by the list above, and then you have even more and without language changes.  Any language features would only make it a bit prettier.

So you can have 100% Kotlin code, using the small Kotlin runtime, the JVM runtime from the JDK, and any other JVM library you want to use.  No need for Java code, just Java (as-in JVM) libraries.

A quick sample of some features:

```
class SomethingSyncd {
    @Synchronized fun syncFoo() {
        
    }
    
    val myLock = Any()
    
    fun foo() {
        synchronized(myLock) {
            // ... code
        }
    }
    
    @Volatile var thing = mapOf(...)
}
```

Comment: Any examples? cos if i write synchronize on method it just wont take it... same with volatile...

Comment: @vach I gave links in my comment, under your question. Synchronized and Volatile are annotations.

Comment: @vach if you have code you tried, it should be included in your question along with any error message.

Comment: @JBNizet I merged in your links

Comment: @vach I added a quick sample of annotations related to this question, things like `CountDownLatch` just port Java samples, or for Kovenant, view the docs for the lib.

Comment: Added more links in the answer @vach

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer, newcomers will appreciate ;)

Comment: I dont think kotlin reserved async await, those are not keywords but library functions so any one is free to use those identifiers... @JaysonMinard maybe fix your update?

Comment: @KeyLay they are only deprecated in the COMMON stdlib, and still are valid for JVM and JS versions of the standard library and will not be deprecated there.

Comment: +1 Kotlin for having an annotation and a keyword with the same name. Couldn't we just have written `synchronized fun foo() ...` ffs?

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman `synchronized` is a keyword in Java, not in kotlin. This answer says that the annotation `@Synchronized` maps to Java's `synchronized` keyword in JVM.

Comment: Yes, I'm pointing out that having to use an annotation in Kotlin makes it feel like synchronization is an afterthought.

Comment: Look at @JeffreyBlattman Kotlin CoRoutines for other models of working with shared resources, synchronization, etc.  This is the intended path, whereas the annotation is for when not coding to the coroutine model and using the VM model.

Comment: @JaysonMinard Coroutines have nothing at all do to with semaphores / synchronization. You have all the same problems in that regard whether you're using Coroutines or a thread. In almost all cases the use of coroutines is equivalent to using a thread, unless you are using, or are writing your own native backend for the library and can take advantage of non-blocking IO at the OS level.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman I'm referring to other patterns that Kotlin focuses on instead of making `synchronized` the preferred way of doing concurrent programming, it pushes it aside a bit and favors other models, including actors, flows, coroutines, ... Something to consider if you don't think it values `synchronized` heavily by making it an annotation over a keyword.

Comment: Please do not vandalize "your" answer to make a personal statement about your disapproval of the company behind Kotlin. Once you have published your answer it is no longer your property.  If you wish to be personally disassociated from the Q&A, there are approved ways to do that.

Comment: @StephenC reverted (all)

Answer (score 12):

I'll answer my own question since actual answer to my question was somewhere deep in kotlin discussions.

What confused me at the time coming from Java was that concurrency keywords were not language keywords they were annotations? to me it seemed strange that important concepts like synchronization were handled through annotations, but now it makes perfect sense. Kotlin is going in the direction of being a platform agnostic language, it's not going to only work on JVM but pretty much anything. So synchronized and volatile were very specific to JVM, they might not be needed in javascript for example.

In a nutshell Kotlin has everything Java has (except package visibility) and much more, a huge difference that no other language has is coroutines. But there is nothing you can write in Java that you cant do in Kotlin... (as far as I am aware)

Answer (score 2):

I think `suspend` is a concurrency keyword:

```kotlin
fun main() = runBlocking {
    launch { doSomething() }
}

suspend fun doSomething() {
    delay(1_000)
    println("Something was done")
}
```

Comment: yes it is, though if i remember correctly coroutines were not a thing when i asked this question )

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a flaw in your base assumption.  Although Kotlin is primarily a JVM language, it does run on other platforms.  Personally, I haven't worked with another language that supports "synchronized" as a language concept.  So the Kotlin devs had the choice of emulating synchronization or relying on other mechanism.  They choose the later.  Kotlin supports "synchronization" through Mutex and single threading access through a variety of mechanisms, coroutines being the most popular.

As others have stated, there are annotations to expose JVM specific features like synchronization, but that means your Kotlin code will be tied to the JVM.  Generally speaking that's probably not a big deal.

I don't have any specific knowledge of how the JVM implements synchronization, but I assume it's using a Mutex under the covers.  Mutex is a core part of C, which is what the JVM is written in.