# Thread-safe access to a Kotlin var from multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines, safe-publication

Consider the following Kotlin code:

```
import kotlin.concurrent.thread

fun main() {
    println("Press <Enter> to terminate.")

    var interrupted = false

    val worker = thread {
        while (!interrupted) {
            println("Working...")
            Thread.sleep(1000L)
        }
    }

    System.`in`.read()

    println("Terminating...")
    interrupted = true

    worker.join()

    println("Terminated.")
}
```

as well the same example rewritten using coroutines:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

fun main() = runBlocking {
    println("Press <Enter> to terminate.")

    var interrupted = false

    val worker = launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        while (!interrupted) {
            println("Working...")
            delay(1000L)
        }
    }

    System.`in`.read()

    println("Terminating...")
    interrupted = true

    worker.join()

    println("Terminated.")
}
```

Both examples will work in most cases, and yet both are broken, because, at the bytecode level, a `boolean` variable accessed from more than a single thread is represented as a `kotlin.jvm.internal.Ref.BooleanRef` which is not thread-safe.

It's worth mentioning that a Java compiler will require `interrupted` to be `final` and the identical Java code will simply fail to compile.

#### Questions

1. What is the canonical way to rewrite the above code using just the standard library (i. e. w/o `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean` or [`kotlinx.atomicfu.AtomicBoolean`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.atomicfu))?
2. How can the above code (the 2nd fragment which uses coroutines) be rewritten in the most portable way, so that it can target *Kotlin/Multiplatform*?

Comment: Did you tried @Volatile annotation for thread solution? For the coroutine one i'll recommend you to look over StateFlow.

Comment: @animesh-sahu that is common misconception that making a variable volatile solves concurrency problem.
please read [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html)

Comment: @MehdiYari It's a misconception that it makes increment modifications atomic. Here it is only read from one thread and written from another, so `@Volatile` does solve the problem. But OP is asking for a cross-platform solution and Volatile is JVM-only.

Comment: “just the standard library (i.e. w/o `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean`)” — but that class _is_ part of the Java standard library (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35521983/10134209)), so for Kotlin/JVM the answer would simply be to use that.  (This only a partial frame challenge, though, as it's not in Kotlin/Multiplatform.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html)

The first solution is a thread-safe data structure like `AtmoicBoolean`

```kotlin
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean
import kotlin.concurrent.thread
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

fun main() {
    println("Press <Enter> to terminate.")
    val interrupted = AtomicBoolean()
    val worker = thread {
        while (!interrupted.get()) {
            println("Working...")
            Thread.sleep(1000L)
        }
    }

    System.`in`.read()
    println("Terminating...")
    interrupted.set(true)
    worker.join()
    println("Terminated.")
}

// coroutine way
fun main_2() = runBlocking {
    println("Press <Enter> to terminate.")
    val interrupted = AtomicBoolean()
    val worker = launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        while (!interrupted.get()) {
            println("Working...")
            delay(1000L)
        }
    }

    System.`in`.read()
    println("Terminating...")
    interrupted.set(true)
    worker.join()
    println("Terminated.")
}
```

Second solution is [Mutual exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion)

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.Mutex
import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.withLock

val mutex = Mutex()

fun main() = runBlocking {
    println("Press <Enter> to terminate.")
    var interrupted = false
    val worker = launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        while (mutex.withLock { !interrupted }) {
            println("Working...")
            delay(1000L)
        }
    }

    System.`in`.read()
    println("Terminating...")
    mutex.withLock { interrupted = true }
    worker.join()
    println("Terminated.")
}
```

I am just using two solutions for this problem in here you can find [another solution](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html)

> How can the above code (the 2nd fragment, which uses coroutines) be rewritten in the most portable way so it can target Kotlin/Multiplatform?

I don't have much experience in kotlin-multiplatform, but you can't use `Dispacher.IO` in Kotlin multiplatform because it's bound to the JVM, so if you’re
using Kotlin/JavaScript or Kotlin/Native projects, you won’t be able to use it.